# Having trouble naming title, x and y axis on histogram, getting error message

Tags: r, histogram

I'm having trouble putting labels on my histogram of this subset of data:

```
hist(Familiar$letterCount, main = "Letter count of Familiar Words", xlab = "Letter Count", ylab = "Frequency", abline(v = mean(Familiar$letterCount), col = "black"))
```

and I'm getting the error message:

```
invalid breakpoints produced by 'breaks(x)' null r
```

I apologize if this was not properly formatted for stack overflow, but what mistake am I making here?

Comment: abline needs to be outside the hist call.

Answer (score 1):

you have included 'abline' function inside 'hist' function. Try the following:

```
hist(Familiar$letterCount, main = "Letter count of Familiar Words",
     xlab = "Letter Count", ylab = "Frequency")

abline(v = mean(Familiar$letterCount), col = "black")
```

Comment: Thank you much! forgot to respond but this worked perfectly!